# What the different between those two Golang function return

Tags: go

What the different between those two Golang functions, are they the same with each other?

```
func foo1() (ret string) {
    ret = "hi there"
    return
}

func foo2() string {
    ret := "hi there"
    return ret
}
```

which is better?

Comment: See [named return values](https://go.dev/tour/basics/7).

Comment: Note that there's one place where you *must* use named return values, when using `defer` with a function that changes the return value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These two functions are identical: https://go.dev/play/p/_6KT5thL2Sj

- `foo2` uses implicit return.
- `foo1` uses [named return values](https://go.dev/tour/basics/7) and `naked/bare` return. Some consider this a code smell: [proposal: Go 2: remove bare return](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/21291)